# Select form option on page load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to select the option contained within a php variable on page load.

```
<?php
$pre = 78;
?>

<select id="form8" name="form8">
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="64">64</option>
<option value="78">78</option>
<option value="82">82</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form8").val("<?php echo $pre; ?>");
}
</script>
```

Expected output should be,

```
<select id="form8" name="form8">
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="64">64</option>
<option value="78" selected="selected">78</option>
<option value="82">82</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qQZVN/1/

Comment: updated post with expected output

Comment: Yes, I did miss the #, however after fixing it, it still doesn't work. Upon page load, 15 is selected on the drop down box instead of 78

Comment: i have updated my answer try without quotes, also try hard coding the value to see if it works like `$('#form8').val(78);`

Comment: still nothing, so far i've tried      $("#form8").val("78");
    $("form8").attr('value',78);
    $('#form8').val(78);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/48DVL/1/)

```
$('#form8').val("<?php echo $pre; ?>") ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use HTML to set `selected='selected'`? Seems easier, and supports non-JS users.

Comment: I agree with you. I see no sense in the js too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form8").val(<?php echo $pre; ?>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select#form8').val('<?php echo $pre; ?>');
```